# pipelining through multiple functions in powershell

Tags: function, powershell, pipelining

The user launchs a script called wrapper.ps1
It has

```
param(
  [string]$command,
  [string]$item=''
  etc
)
```

I then evaluate this with

```
switch -wildcard ($command) {
  "command1" {function1 $item;}
  "command2" {function2 $item;} 
  etc. 
 }
```

Then I have a function1 like:

```
function function1 {
   param([string] $itemname =''}
   #etc...then:
   $summary = @{blah1 = $blah1; blah2= $blah2; blah3= $blah3; }
   return $summary
```

$blah# are simple strings.
The question is how can I pipeline into function1 via wrapper.ps1?
I'd like to call this script like this:

wrapper.ps1 command1 filename |ft blah1,blah3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose to return a hashtable so you can exploit it from the pipeline

```
wrapper.ps1  "command1" "item" | select -ExpandProperty values
```

or

```
wrapper.ps1 "command1" "item" | % {foreach ($hash in $_.keys){write-host "the key is $hash the value is $($_[$hash])"}}
```

Comment: everything works when I call the ps1 file directly-apparently, and the information you provided is great!  The problem I am actually experiencing is I am calling the wrapper.ps1 from inside a .cmd file like: powershell.exe -command wrapper.ps1 %* and I think this breaks the piping capability since %* may not know what to do with the pipe...hrmmmph